# flex box grid layout with titles underneath pictures

Tags: html, css, flexbox

currently I have the grid system that I desire with flexbox, however the titles underneath are just slightly to the side and I want them centered. If anyone has an idea on how to fix this let me know it would be greatly appreciated!

```css
.row{
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content:center;
}

.col{
flex: 0 0 calc(15%);
margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="item-1 col">

 <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-342" src="http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/monkey/21.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" />

Black and White Copies

</div>
<div class="item-2 col">

<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-341" src="http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/monkey/21.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" />

Binding

</div>
<div class="item-3 col">

<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-343" src="http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/monkey/21.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" />

Color Copies

</div>
<div class="item-4 col">

<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-345" src="http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/monkey/21.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" />

Stickers

</div>
<div class="item-5 col">

<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-346" src="http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/monkey/21.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" />

Lamination

</div>
<div class="item-6 col">

<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-344" src="http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/monkey/21.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" />

Other Services

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's illogical to use `calc` here, rather than just `15%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you just want the text center? See this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LkGpsLfbqA0gn9sdxpEn?p=preview) as an example.

```
.col{
flex: 0 0 calc(15%);
margin: 5px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Yup I guess that was easier than I thought it was going to be. I thought I tried that but I guess not. Thank you so so much for your help! @JohnD

Answer (score 1):

Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bss860yn/)?

```
.row{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.col{
    flex: 0 0 calc(15%);
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Yup I guess that was easier than I thought it was going to be. I thought I tried that but I guess not. Thank you so so much for your help! @Michele Mariotti

Answer (score 0):

I created separate p tags for your text content and made them to be text-align center.

```css
.row{
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content:center;

}

.col{
flex: 0 0 calc(15%);
margin: 5px;
text-align:center;
}

p{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="item-1 col">

 <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-342" src="http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/monkey/21.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" />

  <p>  Black and White Copies<p>

</div>
<div class="item-2 col">

<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-341" src="http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/monkey/21.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" />

  <p>  Binding <p>

</div>
<div class="item-3 col">

<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-343" src="http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/monkey/21.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" />

   <p> Color Copies </p>

</div>
<div class="item-4 col">

<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-345" src="http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/monkey/21.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" />

<p>Stickers</p>

</div>
<div class="item-5 col">

<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-346" src="http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/monkey/21.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" />

<p>Lamination</p>

</div>
<div class="item-6 col">

<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-344" src="http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/monkey/21.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" />

<p>Other Services</p>

</div>
</div>
```